# Can't update table fields depending on value on number

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

So I have a form where I can select an excel file, it'll make a table which is an exact copy of that file, and then it'll try to match fields from that table with a project table and update the matching fields. The issue is sometimes the projects field won't update. As an example the existing value is 1.0319. If my excel file has 1.026 it will not update. 1.026 does appear in the temp table. But if I change it to 1.016 in the excel it will update. Then if I change it back to 1.026, it will update. However if I change it to 1.0319, the original value, it won't update. It honestly has me baffled and I wonder if it's actually a fault in access or VB. Here's the code, I simplified it a bit by removing the other fields it tests for and the excel load as that works fine.

```
Dim sSQL As String
Dim db As Database
Dim recTemp, recProj As Recordset    
Dim intUpdatedRecordCount As Integer
Dim bUpdatedRecord As Boolean
Dim sSelectedFieldsQuery As String  

sSelectedFieldsQuery = "P_Ratio"

'Update Generator data with imported table
Set db = CurrentDb()  

sSQL = "SELECT TempImpProjRes.Desc, TempImpProjRes.ElemName, TempImpProjRes.BusA, TempImpProjRes.ID, TempImpProjRes.ProjID, " & _
                    "TempImpProjRes.ElemID, " & sSelectedFieldsQuery & " FROM TempImpProjRes"

Set recTemp = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbConsistent)

'begin to loop over imported data
If recTemp.RecordCount > 0 Then
    recTemp.MoveFirst
    Do While Not recTemp.EOF
        sSQL = "SELECT Projects.ProjID, Projects.ElemID,"Projects.P_Ratio FROM Projects WHERE Projects.ProjID=" & recTemp!ProjID & " AND Projects.ElemID=" & recTemp!ElemID"
        Set recProj = db.OpenRecordset(sSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbConsistent)

            intUpdatedRecordCount = 0
            bUpdatedRecord = False                                           
            bUpdatedRecord = Not CDbl(Format(recProj!P_Ratio, "0.00")) = CDbl(Format(recTemp!P_Ratio, "0.00"))
            intUpdatedRecordCount = intUpdatedRecordCount + BooleanToInt(bUpdatedRecord)                

            'if any field has been updated then we need to update the respective value in the Projects table
            If intUpdatedRecordCount > 0 Then
                recProj.Edit
                recProj!P_Ratio = CDbl(Format(recTemp!P_Ratio, "0.0000"))
                recProj!Updated = Date
                recProj.Update
            End If

        recProj.Close
        Set recProj = Nothing
        recTemp.MoveNext
    Loop
End If

recTemp.Close
db.Close
Set recTemp = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
```

Comment: I'd be suspicious of the floating point equality check; even with the rounding, I'm still not sure it will work as expected in every instance.  You might be better off using `Decimal`.

Comment: I'm new to VB/access, you're referring to recProj!P_Ratio = CDbl(Format(recTemp!P_Ratio, "0.0000")) I take it? The field is a double in both tables. If I change the field to a decimal then I get an error saying data truncation may occur and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I'm talking about the assignment to `bUpdatedRecord` which is based on `CDbl`; this might be worth inspecting in a debugger, and you could consider changing how you do the comparison.  Upon further consideration, I don't even know that you need to do `Decimal`, but I'd recommend to take a close look at what this is doing.

Comment: I think I know what was happening. The "0.00" rounds it to the nearest hundredth, and both .01319 and .0126 were rounding to .013. I changed to "0.0000" and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If it makes you feel any better, I completely missed that too.